# Problems with joining in for loop

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i need help with this script. I have website in two languages, lt and en. In my javascript i want to join months and language two chars. Like if language english it would be montsen if lithuanian monthslt, but i dont know how to make it at for loop, ive tried (months+langdat) but that aint working. So how can i fix it?

```
    var langdat = "<?php echo $LanDate; ?>";
    var monthsen = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var monthslt = ['Sau', 'Vas', 'Kov', 'Bal', 'Geg', 'Bir','Lie', 'Rgp', 'Rgs', 'Spa', 'Lap', 'Grd'];
    for(var j=0;j<(months+langdat).length;j++){
        if(date[1]==months[j]){
            date[1]=months.indexOf(months[j])+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ... You probably gave -1. I know my mistake, i want to make it work, but dont know how, thats why im here. Jeez.

Comment: You are probably given -1/-2 due to poorly constructed question. Neither your description nor the code describes what you want and why your feeling it is not working. People here does not know what you want to do. So, you have to mention what would be the right result and what you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Reference the array based on the `langdat` variable and fetch the data

```js
var langdat = "lithuanian";
var monthsen = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var monthslt = ['Sau', 'Vas', 'Kov', 'Bal', 'Geg', 'Bir', 'Lie', 'Rgp', 'Rgs', 'Spa', 'Lap', 'Grd'];

//Refrence the array based on the language
var months = langdat == "english" ? monthsen : monthslt;

//Get month from the array
var month = months[new Date().getMonth()];

alert(month);
```